# Search payment records information in Netsuite using Suitelet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Need to get payment data from Transaction >> Payable >> Pay single vendor form and create a data file. This has been done with an eventscript (add button), a clientscript and a Suitelet by searching currentRecord data from client script to Suitelet and generated a file. However, searching Transaction record type could not get payer payment department and cost center data as I know. So any advice and recommendation from Netsuite experts on how can get these payer data from Netsuite with the existing Transaction information on the Bill Payment form, like payment check number, entity id, transaction number, etc ?

Answer (score 0):

When using the N/search module the following 3 tools are invaluable for retrieving data from netsuite transactions.

Netsuite records browser (shows all of the fields, available search filters, and joins ect.)

https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2020_1/script/record/vendorpayment.html

Another great tool is an extension called Netsuite Field Explorer developed by Michoel Chaikin

you can also turn on field ids in your account by navigating to Home->Set preferences->General tab->Set defaults->Show internal ids
(This will show the field id when you click on the field "What is this?" link directly on the record)

between the three you should be able to get everything you need to run a search and retrieve the data you are looking for.

Depending on your needs you can either search.create (return multiple records) or search.lookupfield(return a single record)

Comment: Thanks Aaron. The information provided did help me a lot.  I used SuiteQL as a tool to query tables directly, got some results with most data I need. I see an option can use N/query module to get this work as an option. However, I am confused with Schema browser and Record Browser. Search record has no option for transactionLine and classification. I would like to use search record option. Should instead search item and class from Transaction Records? Payer information is in Product Category, that is reflected in schema as classification. Is this right?

Comment: The following is a great article by Eric G. that explains a little more in depth about the records browser. https://stoic.software/effective-suitescript/records-browser/. As for the Search record option I am assuming you mean the N/search module, which is the option I use since I understand how it works in netsuite, better than I understand the N/query (As I understand it, they are very similar in how they retrieve, someone else can chime in to address/correct that.) Searches do return both mainline and line item data.

Comment: When I look at the records browser there is both class and category for filter options on an Item.

Comment: As a side note, in N/query you are essentially accessing the SQL data directly without any joins ect. in N/search you would access the record with all of its joins to make it what it is (most sublist are joined data). But once again I think it depends on what you are more familiar with that will determine what you use.